Detect Duplicates in a Secret Santa
Imagine a Secret Santa with $n$ people. Due to a mix-up, there is a small chance that some people were assigned the same name. Is there any method by which the participants, without the help of a trusted third party, can determine if any two or more people were assigned the same name? If no duplicates exist, the process should not reveal anybody's assignment (or at least, it should be infeasible to determine who was assigned who). Assume that it's not possible to make a statement or message anonymously; if someone shares a number or word, everybody will know who shared it.
I was thinking of using a method similar to a PKI:

Order the list of participants alphabetically
Each participant assigns each participant on the list an arbitrary large prime number, in ascending order of their position on the list (i.e. The person at position 2 would receive a number greater than the person at position 1)
They share the product of these prime numbers along with the prime number relating to the person they were assigned

I couldn't figure out where to go from here, and I'm not sure if this line of thinking will lead to a solution. I was wondering if anyone knows of an algorithm for this problem or if any papers have been published regarding it.

I suppose you mean with "impossible to know" just hard to compute? In that case, there may be a very simple solution: just fix some function $f$ that is easy to compute but hard to reverse (think: hash function, discrete logarithm). Let people share $f(the name they got)$. You can easily check if the outcome is the same, but not what names they got.

I thought of that, but since all the names are known, someone could just hash every name to figure out everybody's assignments.

You say that everything said is public, what prevents them to do a public key scheme to communicate privately?

First, note that people can communicate privately using public key encryption, then establishing a private channel.
Then people A communicates a hash function to everyone except people B. Everyone send the hashed name to B, who can assert there is no mix-up between everyone except him. Then do the same with two other people as A and B to know if the original B shares in common with someone (other than the new B). We then do a third round to check if the two last B people share the same name.

As an addition: the public key requires some care to avoid the problem from my comment. If each person just announces their public key, then everyone can detect each other's messages by just computing all $n$ possible messages. So they should first establish private channels that cannot be eavesdropped between each person and person A and person B. Also: you need a third round to check if the two $B$'s are the same.

Fair. What do you mean by "If the two B's are the same? The can decide that A and B are not the same in second round. The only exception is that for three people, we need three rounds

@MatthewSpam the problem could also be solved by making B create (n-1) symmetric keys and transmitting one to each person right? Then each person would encrypt their hash with that key and not the public key of B.

@caduk If you have two rounds, then you have two people who are the "B" person reviewing the hashed names they got. But then nobody has checked if these two reviewers have the same name, so someone else still has to check that.

@MatthewSpam Indeed
